# How do I compute this integrals?

Tags: integration, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I have the following question:

> Let $\Omega_1=\Omega_2=[0,1]$, $A_1,A_2$ the borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$, $\mu_1$ is the lebesgue measure and $\mu_2$ the counting measure.Let $$C=\{(x,x)|x\in [0,1]\}$$ Compute the Integrals $$\int_{[0,1]}\left(\int_{[0,1]}\chi_C d\mu_1\right)d\mu_2\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\int_{[0,1]}\left(\int_{[0,1]}\chi_C d\mu_2\right)d\mu_1$$

I somhow strugle since $\chi_C(x,x)=1$ for $x\in [0,1]$ and otherwise $0$, but in both of this integrals we first integrate only over $[0,1]$ not over the product, so I don't know what to say about $\chi_C$. Could someone help me?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Note that the characteristic function $\chi_C=\chi_C\left(x,y \right):\left[0,1\right]^2\to \mathbb{R}$ is a function of two variables. So, when you do the iterated integral, you should fix one variable and integrate with respect to the other. Does it make sense?

Comment: so when I only want to compute $\int_{[0,1]}\chi_C d\mu_1$ I need to fix a $y\in [0,1]$ and then I get that $\int_{[0,1]}\chi_C d\mu_1=0$ since it is only 1 if x=y but this is only the case at one point, but a point has measure 0 therefore we have also here 0 rhight?

Comment: Is it formally correct if I would do it as follows? $\int_{[0,1]}\chi_C d\mu_1=\mu_1(\chi_C(y,y))=\mu_1(1)=0$ then we only have $\int_{[0,1]} 0 d\mu_2$ but then this is also 0 rhight?  


On the other hand we fix $x$ and have $\int_{[0,1]}\chi_C(x,y) d\mu_2=\mu_2(\chi_C(x,x))=\mu_2(1)=1$ Then we have $\int_{[0,1]} 1 d\mu_1=\mu_1([0,1]=1$

Comment: I don't think $\mu_1\left(\chi_C\left(x,y\right)\right)$ is formally correct. Maybe you'd like to write $\mu_1\left(C\right)$ wouldn't you?

Comment: Ah yes this would make more sense, but then it is also $0$ and on the other side $\mu_2(C)=1$ right? Or could I also write $\mu_1(\{\chi_C(y,y)\})$ and $\mu_2(\{\chi_C(x,x)\})$

Comment: I don't think $\mu_2\left(C\right)=1$ since $\mu_2$ is a counting measure, which means it measures the number of a set. In this case, the number of $C$ would be infinite, so $\mu_2\left(C\right)=\infty$. So you can see the integral on the left would be 0 and the one on the right would be $\infty$.

Comment: You can write $\mu_1\left(\left\{\chi_C\left(y,y\right)\right\}\right)$. Yet it doesn't seem to be equal to $\mu_1\left(C\right)$, I think, because technically, $\left\{\chi_C\left(y,y\right)\right\}=\left\{1\right\}$ if $y\in \left[0,1\right]$.

Comment: Okey I see it, but on the right, we compute $\int_{[0,1]} \chi_C(x,y) d\mu_2=\mu_2(C)=\infty$ right? And then how can I write the second integral, because I don't think that i can write $\int_{[0,1]} \infty d\mu_1=\infty$ can I? Because in the other part with 0 this can be done.

Comment: Yeah the the first integral is correct. I don't think you can write $\int_{\left[0,1\right]}\infty d\mu_1=\infty$ either. You may as well write the integral is equal to $\infty$

Comment: ah okey thank you